# log4j2 XML Rolling File Appender - Slight changes in appender makes a working xml file code not work

Tags: log4j2

I have a log4j2 xml file appender that is completely working and rolls back the files after every minute. I tried to change that rollback to once per day with some tweaks on the code but now it's not working. What am I missing?

This is the old XML file appender(the working one):

```
        <!-- Rolling File Appenders -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName=".\logs\log${date:yyyyMMdd}.log" 
    filePattern=".\logs\oldLogs\log_%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-3level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3">
            <Delete basePath=".\logs\oldLogs" maxDepth="2">
            <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="3" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>          
    </RollingFile>
```

This is the new one for daily rolling (does not work):

```
        <!-- Rolling File Appenders -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName=".\logs\log${date:yyyyMMdd}.log" 
    filePattern=".\logs\oldLogs\log_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-3level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
            <Delete basePath=".\logs\oldLogs" maxDepth="2">
            <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10"/>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>          
    </RollingFile>
```

Edit:
Behavior I'm Expecting:
~Will generate logs per day and store the logs the day before in this folder: ".\logs\oldLogs\"
~Keeps only the 10 most recent logs and deletes the older logs

Current Behavior:
~Generates log per day but by tomorrow, does not roll the file to this folder: ".\logs\oldLogs\"
~Does not delete any log files

Comment: What do you mean "[it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)" - what is the actual behavior that you're seeing and what is undesirable about it?

Comment: @D.B. added a clearer explanation on expected and current behavior. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to make the `fileName` attribute of the `RollingFile` a constant. The most recent logs will always be contained in this file, so I don't really see it being necessary to put a date on the file name. When the log is archived the date will be added to the file name per the `filePattern`.

Additionally, you can remove the `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` and the `max` attribute of the `DefaultRolloverStrategy`. The `max` attribute is used with the "integer counter" mentioned in description of the [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) `filePattern` parameter and since you're not using that counter the `max` won't help you.

I believe this should work for you:

```
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName=".\logs\applog.log"
        filePattern=".\logs\oldlogs\applog_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-3level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath=".\logs\oldlogs" maxDepth="2">
                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```